# Replace Java class in overall code with custom class loader

Tags: java, classloader

I have a Java application and I want to create a Class Loader to substitute all invokation/instance of a Java classes to another one

I made this class loader:

```java
public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        if (name.equals("qualified.name.of.original.Class")) {
            return super.findClass("qualified.name.of.New.Class");
        }

        return super.findClass(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if (name.equals("qualified.name.of.original.Class")) {
            return super.loadClass("qualified.name.of.New.Class");
        }

        return super.loadClass(name);
    }

}
```

Then I start my application with `-Djava.system.class.loader=qualified.name.of.CustomClassLoader`

But it doesn't work, the original class is used as usual. How can I achieve the result?